# LCD parallel interfaces

Tags: lcd, interface, parallel

I might not be able to find an LCD with a 24 bit parallel interface, which is what my controller requires.  I have seen 18 bit parallel interfaces, though.  I assume that I could really just use the lower 6 bits of each color and not use the other two bits per color channel.  All I would have to do is make sure that my color palettes are adjusted accordingly, right?

Comment: there is the chumby screen/psp screen from sparkfun.
(both are 24bit parallel.)
ps: what is you controller? i cannot seem to find one.

Comment: since your other question was deleted, noone but moderators can see it.

Comment: have you looked at the PSP screen? it's 24bit parallel.
<br /> Where did you find the lcd controller? I looked for a long time for one that works with 24 bit parallel.

Comment: I'm using an Amulet Technologies controller.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this without issue.

However, you want to use the *Upper* (e.g. MSBs) of the digital output, discard the least significant bits. Otherwise, you will get all sorts of interesting effects.
(for instance, a gradient would be "Multiplied", in that a simple span from black to red would repeat twice, provided you're discarding the MSB of the signal).

I currently have a similar project, which uses a 16 bit graphics controller, with a 18 bit LCD. In this case, you connect the 16 bit interface to the MSBs of the LCD, and ground the additional LSBs. What you are proposing is simply the inverse.

---

Note: I've always thought of the MSBs as being "Upper" - This may simply be a terminology disconnect. Anyways, MSB and LSB are a far better way to describe the bus.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification!  This opens up the possibilities for my LCD search quite a bit, I think.